# A fixed size row with overlapping elements

Tags: html, css, sass

What would be the simplest way to create a row of elements which, when they do not fit side-by-side on one row, will overlap each other evenly instead of wrapping?

It should look a bit like this:

```css
ul {
  width: 100px;
}

li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
</ul>
```

but with any number of items. This example will eventually wrap, which I don't want. Also, it would be preferable if the elements wouldn't overlap when there's enough space for all of them to be completely visible.

The child elements will be containing images, and will all be of the same size. I'm using a `ul` here for demonstration, but if something else works better than I'm all for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not perfect, but maybe it is the right way:

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: orange;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}
li > div {
  position: absolute;
  
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><div>Content1</div></li>
  <li><div>Content2</div></li>
  <li><div>Content3</div></li>
  <li><div>Content4</div></li>
  <li><div>Content5</div></li>
  <li><div>Content6</div></li>
  <li><div>Content7</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The `li`s wont be contained by the parent.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what you want. No reason for downvote!

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted your answer. What I meant was that the parent shouldn't exceed the given width. All the child elements should stay within the parent. In your answer it doesn't matter if you set a width to the parent, the children will overflow anyway. I want them to overlap each other instead.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It is not perfect, but maybe you can use it.

Comment: Actually this is just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that comes to my mind is to use flexbox in this case. Just add the property `display: flex;` to the parent `ul` tag and see what's happening with whatever children you add :)

```
ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
li {
  width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: This works, but it requires that the width of the children is changed when their amount changes. I was hoping there would be a way where I didn't have to touch the styling as the number of children changes dynamically.